# Move to/move in the UK(preposition)

Tags: prepositions

Let's say you were asked what are your plans in the future. And you say:

> It has always been my dream to move to another country, particularly **to** the UK.

Or

> It has always been my dream to move to another country, particularly **in** the UK.

Can I use them interchangeably? Any reference if not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the constructions are parallel:

> Move to another country
>
> Move to the UK

You can say "move in the UK" only if you mean the movement stays inside the UK, and in the context of changing house you would normally say "move to London" since "in the UK" is understood from context.

It would be possible to say

> ... particularly to a town in the UK.

as this still implies "[move] to somewhere".

(Also the UK is cold, damp and dark in winter. Are you sure about this dream?)

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the relative clause construction(oh man, I put my focus on the preposition that's why). There's a personal question there, my answer is YES-I've got already an employer in east sussex area. Does it have the same weather condition as what you have just said?

Comment: Compared to the Phillipines?  Yes, it's cold and damp!  (though some days are nicer) Good luck with your Job, you're moving to my neck of the woods, and there is quite a big local Filipino community, mostly in nursing.